# How to get a border within another border in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put many borders within each other in HTML/CSS

I've tried making multiple Divs in CSS that create borders, and putting one border DIV around the entire body, and then separate divs around the certain headings and paragraphs I want to also have borders.  When I try to do this, the only border that shows up is the border around the entire body.

```css
div.a {
  border: 5px green solid;
}

div.b {
  border: 5px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <h1>Victoria's Journal</h1>

    <h2>So fresh and so clean</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected , are we missing parts of your CSS  ?

Comment: The snippet seems to work fine. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I also see both the red and green borders. If you want to add space between them you could add a `margin : 3px;` to the "div.b" CSS class. Otherwise we'll need additional clarification.

Comment: when i run in sublime, and open the browser, it only shows the outer border